# Galaxy mega 5.8 programming on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I've Downloaded and Installed Samsung Kies for my "Galaxy mega 5.8 I9152"
also I Checked the USB Debugging, Allow mock location and stay Awake on Developer Options

but When I want to Run android program on my device using Eclipse Helios "Version: 3.6.2" ;
on the "Android Device chooser" Window, My Device is marked as unknown. how can I fix it?

also I'm running those on Windows 8 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this Myself

I Updated **Android SDK Tools to ver.22**

also installed **Android SDK build-tools**